# Uploading dashboards to Elastic Search Kibana for Beats/Topbeats

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, kibana-4

I've followed the instructions outlined on this repo https://github.com/elastic/beats-dashboards after cloning it locally and attempting to run the script to load the dashboards. I however receive this as the response, which appears that nothing is being created. I am currently trying to run this against an AWS created Elastic Cluster, and haven't seen where this might be a problem but maybe it is the issue. I've also tried the path with the port number (as shown), without, and without adding the https thinking maybe it had some other resolution pattern. Any ideas would be much appreciated! -thanks

```
$ ./load.sh -url "https://search-theserver-5zxxn6zdjtlty74bw35irnppom.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443"
Loading dashboards to https://search-theserver-5zxxn6zdjtlty74bw35irnppom.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443 in .kibana
Loading search Cache-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"Cache-transactions","_version":7,"created":false}
Loading search DB-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"DB-transactions","_version":7,"created":false}
Loading search Default-Search:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"Default-Search","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search Errors:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"Errors","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search Filesystem-stats:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"Filesystem-stats","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search HTTP-errors:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"HTTP-errors","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search MongoDB-errors:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"MongoDB-errors","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search MongoDB-transactions-with-write-concern-0:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"MongoDB-transactions-with-write-concern-0","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search MongoDB-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"MongoDB-transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search MySQL-Transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"MySQL-Transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search MySQL-errors:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"MySQL-errors","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search Packetbeat-Search:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"Packetbeat-Search","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search PgSQL-errors:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"PgSQL-errors","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search PgSQL-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"PgSQL-transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search Proc-stats:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"Proc-stats","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search Processes:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"Processes","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search RPC-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"RPC-transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search System-stats:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"System-stats","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search System-wide:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"System-wide","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search Thrift-errors:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"Thrift-errors","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search Thrift-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"Thrift-transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search Web-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"Web-transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading search Winlogbeat-Search:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"search","_id":"Winlogbeat-Search","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Average-system-load-across-all-systems:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Average-system-load-across-all-systems","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization CPU-usage-per-process:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"CPU-usage-per-process","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization CPU-usage:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"CPU-usage","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Cache-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Cache-transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Client-locations:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Client-locations","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization DB-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"DB-transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Disk-usage-overview:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Disk-usage-overview","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Disk-usage:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Disk-usage","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Disk-utilization-over-time:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Disk-utilization-over-time","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Errors-count-over-time:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Errors-count-over-time","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Errors-vs-successful-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Errors-vs-successful-transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Event-Levels:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Event-Levels","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Evolution-of-the-CPU-times-per-process:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Evolution-of-the-CPU-times-per-process","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization HTTP-codes-for-the-top-queries:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"HTTP-codes-for-the-top-queries","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization HTTP-error-codes-evolution:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"HTTP-error-codes-evolution","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization HTTP-error-codes:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"HTTP-error-codes","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Latency-histogram:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Latency-histogram","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Levels:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Levels","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Memory-usage-per-process:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Memory-usage-per-process","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Memory-usage:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Memory-usage","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization MongoDB-commands:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"MongoDB-commands","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization MongoDB-errors-per-collection:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"MongoDB-errors-per-collection","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization MongoDB-errors:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"MongoDB-errors","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization MongoDB-in-slash-out-throughput:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"MongoDB-in-slash-out-throughput","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization MongoDB-response-times-and-count:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"MongoDB-response-times-and-count","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization MongoDB-response-times-by-collection:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"MongoDB-response-times-by-collection","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Most-frequent-MySQL-queries:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Most-frequent-MySQL-queries","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Most-frequent-PgSQL-queries:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Most-frequent-PgSQL-queries","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization MySQL-Errors:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"MySQL-Errors","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization MySQL-Methods:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"MySQL-Methods","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization MySQL-Reads-vs-Writes:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"MySQL-Reads-vs-Writes","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization MySQL-throughput:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"MySQL-throughput","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Mysql-response-times-percentiles:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Mysql-response-times-percentiles","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Navigation:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Navigation","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Number-of-Events-Over-Time-By-Event-Log:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Number-of-Events-Over-Time-By-Event-Log","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Number-of-Events:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Number-of-Events","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Number-of-MongoDB-transactions-with-writeConcern-w-equal-0:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Number-of-MongoDB-transactions-with-writeConcern-w-equal-0","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization PgSQL-Errors:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"PgSQL-Errors","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization PgSQL-Methods:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"PgSQL-Methods","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization PgSQL-Reads-vs-Writes:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"PgSQL-Reads-vs-Writes","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization PgSQL-response-times-percentiles:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"PgSQL-response-times-percentiles","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization PgSQL-throughput:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"PgSQL-throughput","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Process-status:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Process-status","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization RPC-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"RPC-transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Reads-versus-Writes:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Reads-versus-Writes","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Response-times-percentiles:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Response-times-percentiles","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Response-times-repartition:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Response-times-repartition","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Servers:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Servers","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Slowest-MySQL-queries:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Slowest-MySQL-queries","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Slowest-PgSQL-queries:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Slowest-PgSQL-queries","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Slowest-Thrift-RPC-methods:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Slowest-Thrift-RPC-methods","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Sources:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Sources","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization System-load:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"System-load","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Thrift-RPC-Errors:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Thrift-RPC-Errors","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Thrift-requests-per-minute:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Thrift-requests-per-minute","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Thrift-response-times-percentiles:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Thrift-response-times-percentiles","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Top-10-HTTP-requests:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Top-10-HTTP-requests","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Top-10-memory-consumers:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Top-10-memory-consumers","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Top-10-processes-by-total-CPU-usage:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Top-10-processes-by-total-CPU-usage","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Top-Event-IDs:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Top-Event-IDs","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Top-Thrift-RPC-calls-with-errors:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Top-Thrift-RPC-calls-with-errors","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Top-Thrift-RPC-methods:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Top-Thrift-RPC-methods","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Top-processes:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Top-processes","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Top-slowest-MongoDB-queries:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Top-slowest-MongoDB-queries","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Total-number-of-HTTP-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Total-number-of-HTTP-transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Total-time-spent-in-each-MongoDB-collection:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Total-time-spent-in-each-MongoDB-collection","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading visualization Web-transactions:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Web-transactions","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading dashboard HTTP:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"dashboard","_id":"HTTP","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading dashboard MongoDB-performance:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"dashboard","_id":"MongoDB-performance","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading dashboard MySQL-performance:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"dashboard","_id":"MySQL-performance","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading dashboard Packetbeat-Dashboard:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"dashboard","_id":"Packetbeat-Dashboard","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading dashboard PgSQL-performance:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"dashboard","_id":"PgSQL-performance","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading dashboard Thrift-performance:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"dashboard","_id":"Thrift-performance","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading dashboard Topbeat-Dashboard:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"dashboard","_id":"Topbeat-Dashboard","_version":6,"created":false}
Loading dashboard Winlogbeat-Dashboard:
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"dashboard","_id":"Winlogbeat-Dashboard","_version":6,"created":false}
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
Loading index pattern :
No handler found for uri [/.kibana/index-pattern/] and method [PUT]
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
Loading index pattern :
No handler found for uri [/.kibana/index-pattern/] and method [PUT]
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
Loading index pattern :
No handler found for uri [/.kibana/index-pattern/] and method [PUT]
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
Loading index pattern :
No handler found for uri [/.kibana/index-pattern/] and method [PUT]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, you have to specify slightly different index name, by default the .kibana does not work, nor does .kibana4:

```
./load.sh -url "search-theserver-5zxxn6zdjtlty74bw35irnppom.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com" -index .kibana-4
```

- (You don't need to specify the http:// or port number)